# how to generate a pdf file of a table view in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf

I got a grouped table and i want to make a pdf file containing all the data of the table just like as it 
is in the table. Any suggestion how can i achieve this? Any kind of help would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Need to use `UITableView's` `scrollView` property to create `render` `scrollView` and convert to `PDF`.

Check [ScrollViewToPDF](https://github.com/azu/ScrollViewToPDF/tree/master/ScrollViewToPDF) example

It uses same `scrollview's` `layer`  `renderInContext` but here PDF is created according to your requirement such as one page PDF or multiple page PDF

#### Note : It captures all visible as well as invisible part of scrollView